# We reviewed Data safety section and found discrepancies between your disclosure and app behavior we found the following data types sent off device

Tags: android, google-play, policy

Google reject an update of my app claiming that I am collecting phone number while I am not. I am using only admob and believe it's not collecting phone number.

I can solve the problem and follow google team and adjust the "Data safety" section in the Play Console as they wish but for sure this is a foolish solution.

google team insist that "phone number" is sent off device.

Questions:-

1-How to convince google team that my app is not collecting phone number?

2-Assuming that google team is right, how to double check which data is sent off device while using my app?